# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT Geocode

Tags: api, request

### when i send request this api/link

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia
```

## I keep getting this

```
{
error_message: "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
results: [ ],
status: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this error in IOS and done a-lot of research as the error status and error message is confusing.

status is

> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

but that was not the real problem in my case, the real problem is described in the error message

> Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption

The solution is very simple you need to send the `API KEY` in the query String like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia&key='your-google-api-key'
```